# How do you set singular/plural forms for table names like news?

Tags: naming-conventions, yaml

It's frequently seen in YAML:

```
User:
  tableName: users
  columns:
    ...

     foreignAlias:User
```

And things like that.

But what if the table is called `news`?How will you make it distinguish-able?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is called `news`, I would go for a new name that allows the "plural table name / singular record" pattern like `NewsItems`, `Topics`, or `Reports`.